# C# linq Sum() extension for large numbers

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a simple Sum extension:

```
public static int? SumOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> projection)
{
    return source.Any()
        ? source.Sum(projection)
        : (int?)null;
}
```

But it causes `System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.`

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
public static ulong? SumOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> projection)
{
    return source.Any()
        ? source.Sum(projection)
        : (ulong?)null;
}
```

But Linq Sum does not have overload that returns ulong and compilation error as a result.
Any way to make that work?

Comment: cast `source.Sum(projection)` to 'ulong`

Comment: There might be workaround: `decimal.MaxValue > ulong.MaxValue` returns `true` hence `Sum(e => (decimal)e.Value)`. Have in mind that Linq-to-Sql hates hacks.

Comment: do you need ulong? maybe long will be enough?

Comment: @PTwr it's an extension over IEnumerable which means the L2S is not involved.

Comment: There is an overload of `Sum` that takes a *signed* `long`. Would `source.Sum(x=>(long)x)` be acceptable?

Comment: You can always use `Aggregate(...)` `Sum` is just a specialized version of `Aggregate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement it manually. Here is an example:

```
public static ulong? SumOrNull<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, int> projection)
{
    bool any = false;

    ulong sum = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        any = true;

        //As commented by CodesInChaos,
        //we use the checked keyword to make sure that
        //we throw an exception if there are any negative numbers
        sum = sum + (ulong)checked((uint)projection(item));
    }

    if (!any)
        return null;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to simply cast the result of projection to `long`, eg `source.Sum((long)projection)` ?

Comment: This approach has the advantage that it only enumerates the input sequence once.

Comment: I wouldn't cast directly from a signed int to an unsigned long value. I'd probably use `(ulong)checked((uint)value)` instead.

Comment: I think that it is also doable that way. Although you would have to enumerate twice (as CodesInChaos noted).

Comment: @CodesInChaos, right, you want make sure that you know if there are any negative values.

Answer (score 1):

`Sum` method has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337919(v=vs.110).aspx) for long but you need to pass an `IEnumerable<long>`, in order to do that you can cast the result of the projection to `long`:

```
public static ulong? SumOrNull<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> projection)
{
  return source.Any()
          ? (ulong?)source.Sum(x => (long)projection(x))
          : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on `ulong` (not `long`) you can use `Aggregate` instead of `Sum`:

```
public static ulong? SumOrNull<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
                                        Func<TSource, ulong> projection) {
   return source.Any()
     ? source.Aggregate((ulong?) 0, (s, x) => s + projection(x))
     : null;
}
```